# Apple rejects app because test account not given

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store

Apple rejects app because test account not given.

As App login via OTP only. How can i manage this situtation?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you are using **Firebase** Auth, you can add the test phone number and set the OTP.
on Firebase Console Navigate to Authentication->Sign-in method->phone then add your testing number as in the photo
[image]
then provide it to apple in the test account section as in the photo
[image]

if you are using another provider, I'm sure they have the ability to provide test phone numbers.

Comment: Thanks.. But  sign in required field can provide userName and password field. On the other hand My app login field  mobile number and otp . So how i can provide test mobile number and otp of the app store team ?

Comment: Apple team will know that it's mobile and OTP as they have experienced that many times i guess, and you can write in the notes for the apple team that notes.

Comment: I'am really grateful

Comment: In my current application, we have OTP based login authentication. But OTP for the mobile number is not changed. It is constant. so we provide one test mobile number and OTP for apple review.